# How to extract city from dataframe column (not same format)

Tags: python, pandas

i have this dataframe, and i want to extract cities in a separate column. You can also see, that the format is not same, and the city can be anywhere in the row. How can i extract only cities i a new column?
**Prompt. Here we are talking about German cities.** May be to find a dictionary, that shows all German cities and somehow compare with my dataset?

Here is dictionary of german cities: https://gist.github.com/embayer/772c442419999fa52ca1

**Dataframe**

```
Adresse
0   Karlstr 10, 10 B, 30,; 04916 Hamburg
1   München Dorfstr. 28-55, 22555
2   Marnstraße. Berlin 12, 45666 Berlin
3   Musterstr, 24855 Dresden
... ...
850 Muster Hausweg 11, Hannover, 56668
851 Mariestr. 4, 48669 Nürnberg
852 Hilden Weederstr 33-55, 56889
853 Pt-gaanen-Str. 2, 45883 Potsdam
```

Output

```
Cities
0   Hamburg
1   München
2   Berlin
3   Dresden
... ...
850 Hannover
851 Nürnberg
852 Hilden
853 Potsdam
```

Comment: You say the format is not always the same, but all cities are starting and finishing with `**`. You can use that in a regular expression

Comment: I've updated my answer with a lookup in the cities dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract in a list all the cities from the dictionary you provided ( I asssume it's the 'stadt' `key` ), and then use `str.findall` in your column:

```
cities_ = [cities[n]['stadt'] for n in range(0,len(cities))]
df.Adresse.str.findall(r'|'.join(cities_))

>>>
0    [Karlstr, Hamburg]
1                    []
2                    []
3                    []
4                    []
5                    []
6                    []
7                    []
8                    []
Name: Adresse, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your answer. It is working. Can u explain me whats mean (r'|'  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `str.extract` since all the names are between couple of stars.

```
df["cities"] = df["Adress"].str.extract(r'\*\*(\w+)\*\*')
```

Since it seems the stars are not present in your file, you can do it differently.

Use the dictionary of cities, called `cities` from the file you linked but keep only a unique sequence (called a `set`) of cities.

```
german_cities = set(map(lambda x: x['stadt'], cities))
```

Then, we'll split the address string for each row and lookup in the German cities dictionary.

Since the first argument of apply is the series itself, we just need to tell it to have a look at the set of German cities.

```
def lookup_cities(string, cities):
    splits = string.replace(",", "").split(" ")
    for s in splits:
        if s in cities:
            return s
    return "NaN"

df["Adress"].apply(lookup_cities, args=(german_cities,))
```

Now if you find any `"NaN"` then it's either that a city in your document has a typo or maybe several way to write it, you'll have to investigate yourself.

P.S: I had to remove all the spaces in the cities files otherwise the names wouldn't match. It was just a matter of using find and replace all in my editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to extract the city names, as they are indicated by `**`:

```
import re 
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({"Adresse": ["Karlstr 10, 10 B, 30,; 04916 **Hamburg**", "**München** Dorfstr. 28-55, 22555", "Marnstraße. Berlin 12, 45666 **Berlin**", "Musterstr, 24855 **Dresden**"]})

df['Cities'] = [re.findall(r".*\*\*(.*)\*\*", address)[0] for address in df['Adresse']]
```

This results in:

```
df
                                    Adresse   Cities
0  Karlstr 10, 10 B, 30,; 04916 **Hamburg**  Hamburg
1         **München** Dorfstr. 28-55, 22555  München
2   Marnstraße. Berlin 12, 45666 **Berlin**   Berlin
3              Musterstr, 24855 **Dresden**  Dresden
```